# Do something whenever authentication is successful

Tags: feathersjs

I need to implement a `lastLoggedIn` date field that's updated to the current date everytime a user authenticates successfully.

I thought I might be able to do that by registering an after-hook on the `/auth/local` service, but those hooks are never invoked:

```
  app.service('/auth/local').after({
    all: [
      hook => console.log(hook.result),
    ],
  });
```

That `console.log` never runs. If this is not the way to do this kind of thing, how should I go about doing it?

Comment: I'd try [upgrading to feathers-authentication 1.0](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-authentication/blob/master/docs/migrating.md). It has an `app.on('login', user)` and `app.on('logout', user)` event.